# checkbox losing its default functionality

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list. In that I have some checkboxes. I am trying to get checkboxes checked in two different ways. One is default way, and another one is when I click on 'li'. The link to the code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RNcfQ/1/)

When I click on li, the checkbox checks properly, but when i click on checkbox itself, it does not. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by checking the target of the click event. If it's not an `li` element, don't run your code.

```
$("#divclass li").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
         //Your code   
    }
});
```

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RNcfQ/2/) for an example.

Comment: This works. Why was my code not working. I was already using the click event on LI right? I mean $(".divclass li").click(... ?

Comment: that's because checkbox are get toggled two times and remaining it;s state..as you can see in `patrick` answer

Comment: Your code was not working because when you click on a checkbox (which is a child of an `li` element), the checkbox will get checked as per normal checkbox behaviour. However, because the checkbox is a inside the `li`, your code for the `li` click event is run as well, and the checkbox is unchecked again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use label instead of js.
see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tpmaA/)

```
<div class="divclass" id="divclass">
    <ul>
         <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkclass" class="checkclass" value="1" />Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio nisi, euismod in, pharetra a, ultricies in, diam. Sed arcu. Cras consequat.</label></li>
         <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkclass" class="checkclass" value="2" />Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</label></li>
         <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkclass" class="checkclass" value="3" />Phasellus ultrices nulla quis nibh. Quisque a lectus. Donec consectetuer ligula vulputate sem tristique cursus. Nam nulla quam, gravida non, commodo a, sodales sit amet, nisi.</label></li>
         <li><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkclass" class="checkclass" value="4" />Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</label></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```